# ¿Cómo mostrar mi mensaje en una sola ventana informativa?

Tags: java, java-swing, modal, jdbc, mensajes

Estoy conectandome a una base de datos, cuando realizo el bucle de la consulta ***while(miConsulta.next())*** quiero que salga una ventana con **java Swing** indicando todas las empresas. Ahora mismo funciona del siguiente modo; hay que darle click a aceptar cada vez por cada empresa, no sale todo en un mismo mensaje y una misma ventana.

¿Cómo podría conseguir que me salga el listado completo en una misma ventana?

```
public void ver() {
    try {
        //se crea la conexion
        Connection conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba", "root","");

        //crear objeto statement
        Statement miStatement = conexion.createStatement();

        //ejecutamos SQL
        ResultSet miConsulta = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM enterprise");

        //crea la variable booleana
        boolean existe = false;
        //recorrer  el resultSet

        String formato = "";
        while(miConsulta.next()) {
            System.out.println("nombre empresa: "+miConsulta.getString("name"));
            formato = "nombre empresa: "+miConsulta.getString("name");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frameDos, formato, "Listado de empresas", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("no se puede conectar, el error es el siguiente:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Existe JOptionPane de javax.swing, puedes usar JOptionPane.showMessageDialog para poder mostrar una ventana con esos datos, la cuestion es que tu mismo organices como quieres mostrarlos...

Comment: si justo lo estoy trantando de hacer con JOptionPane pero no termino de comprender como mostrarlos todos juntos y no en una ventana para cada resultado, soy nueva en esto del java Swing, el problema diria que viene al usar el JOptionPane dentro del bucle while, pero si lo coloco fuera salta un error.

Comment: Ah si... que tal si concatenas toda la informacion que quieras mostrar y luego Fuera del loop muestras tu JOptionPane??, creo que el problema esta en que por cada informacion que quieres mostrar estas mostrando un JOptionPane diferente con una porcion de informacion en cada iteracion, en vez de toda junta, intenta eso, por cierto, que tal si pones como  primer parametro del JOptionPane un null??, creo que es bueno tener centrado el mensaje a la pantalla y no al componente.

Comment: Mm no se si termino de entender lo que tratas de decirme podrias ponerme un ejemplo porfavor :)? En cuanto al null, seria cambiar frameDos por null cierto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes sacar de tu loop a tu `JOptionPane` y ademas concatenar un salto de linea al final para poder ver bien tu información en un solo `JOptionPane`:

```
String formato = "";
while(miConsulta.next()){
   System.out.println("nombre empresa: "+miConsulta.getString("name"));
   formato += "nombre empresa: "+miConsulta.getString("name") + "\n";
}

//Fuera del loop mostramos el mensaje 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, formato, "Listado de empresas", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

**Fijarse bien en que ha cambiado**, de esta manera la lista se vera en un solo mensaje, nótese que usamos **formato +=** como asignación en el ciclo,  es muy importante tener esto en cuenta.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por explicarme!! no sabia que debia colocar un += , juto habia probado a colocar el Joptionpane fuera del bucle pero me daba error.